Revision 2: Is this homebrew Warlock patron - the DM - balanced?
Thanks for the advice in the first revision of this homebrew subclass. My daughter's made a few changes:

Master's Knowledge has been dropped to 1st level (the unusual reference to actual numeric HP maximum is deliberate - this is the DM that's giving the info). Otherwise unchanged.
Rule Bending has been dropped to 6th level. Otherwise unchanged.
Plot Armour has been raised to 10th level. Rather than allowing a free casting of Shield, and better death saves; it now grants Resistance to all the damage types of one attack for the rest of the turn, once per day.
Rocks Fall, Everybody Dies has had its templating clarified
Pact of the Die no longer affects saving throws

How are we looking for balance now?
(Again, rather than the implicit CC BY-SA 4.0. licence held by me, this subclass is CC BY-NC-SA 4.0. held by my daughter)

Warlock patron: The DM
Your patron is a puppet-master deity with control over the world around you. You understand that the events that befall you and the people you meet are controlled by the DM, the happenings are controlled by dice, and the whole world is understood like a book of rules by your patron.
Expanded Spell List
The DM lets you choose from an expanded list of spells when you learn a warlock spell. The following spells are added to the warlock spell list for you.



Spell level
Spells




1st
Disguise self, Identify


2nd
Borrowed knowledge, Detect thoughts


3rd
Bestow curse, Sending


4th
Confusion, Fabricate


5th
Dominate person, Modify memory



Master’s knowledge
Starting at 1st level, you can use your patron’s encompassing knowledge of the world to better understand your enemies. As a bonus action, you can ask your patron for information on a creature you can see. You learn all of its damage vulnerabilities, damage resistances, damage immunities, condition immunities, and hit point total. You can do this a number of times per day equal to your charisma modifier.
Rule-bending
Beginning at 6th level, you can use your close understanding of the rules of the multiverse to bend them around yourself. As an action, you can choose one skill or tool; for 10 minutes, you have proficiency with the chosen skill or tool. You cannot use this feature again until you finish a long rest.
Additionally, when you cast a warlock spell, you can change the damage type to any other damage type. You may do this a number of times equal to your warlock level divided by three (rounded down).
Plot armour
Starting at 10th level, your patron has a fondness for you that means you can circumvent the chosen narrative in order to stay alive. Once per day, when you are attacked by an enemy you can see, you can use your reaction to gain resistance to the damage type(s) of the attack until your next turn.
Rocks fall, everybody dies
When you reach 14th level, you can call upon and channel the rage of your patron. Once per day, as an action, you can call forth rocks to drop from the sky within 120 feet of you. These rocks fall in a 10ft radius circle, and all creatures must make a dexterity saving throw against your warlock spell DC or take 8d10 bludgeoning damage, or half as much on a successful save.
Bonus pact boon: Pact of the Die
(prerequisite: DM as patron)

You are gifted a twenty-sided die as a representation of your patron; it is no larger than your palm, and looks however you wish it. You can use this as your spellcasting focus. This die has a number of uses equal to your proficiency bonus, and regains all expended uses at dawn.
You may expend one use of the die to give yourself advantage on an attack roll or ability check; to give another creature you can see disadvantage on an attack roll or ability check; or to roll damage twice and take the higher value
Should your die be lost, you can perform a 1-hour ritual to receive a new one from your patron, which can be done during a short rest. Your die ceases to exist if you die, or perform the 1-hour ritual to summon a new one.


Still weak
As I said in my answer to your last version, I think both Master's Knowledge and Rule-Bending are situational and weak. Those are unchanged and still mostly useless.
Plot Armour
My first reaction here was that it's terrible. Warlocks with the fiend patron get permanent immunity to one damage type and the damage type can be changed. Plot Armour only gives resistance once per day. But then I thought about it some more, and actually think it might be fine. Since you don't have to choose the damage types in advance, you're guaranteed to be able to use it no matter what enemies you end up fighting. You're also not restricted in what damage types you can get resistance to. I think this is fine and ready for play testing.
Rocks fall, everybody dies
This is significantly nerfed from the last revision. If this was a spell it would probably be a 3rd level spell. It has more damage than Fireball but significantly smaller radius. It might be 4th level because of the damage (slightly more than Blight), but not 5th. It's better than Flame Strike, but Flame Strike is a terrible spell. The damage of Rocks fall, everybody dies is comparable to Cone of Cold, but the area is tiny in comparison. My point is that one free (at best) 4th level spell, isn't all that great at 14th level. The Genie patron lets you cast any spell of 6th level or lower as an action, but you need to wait 1d4 long rests before using it again.
I liked this better when it didn't cost an Action. Perhaps a Bonus Action would be appropriate?
Pact of the Die
I like this and think it's ready for play testing.

I would like to add that I really like the flavour here. I think all the features makes sense for a DM patron and the idea of having the DM as a patron is awesome!

Thanks for the further thoughts. For "Rocks Fall...", that makes sense; there's a number of knobs to twiddle here - action type, radius, damage dice. It taking no action possibly leads to weird timing questions, so we might go one of the other routes.
I'm unconvinced Master's Knowledge and Rule Bending are really awful; MK matches (is better than) a Way of the Cobalt Soul Monk feature, and RB includes the Knowledge Domain Divinity feature, plus a bit more. From experience, not all parties have a lock-picking Rogue...

Master's Knowledge does in no way match Extract Aspects from Cobalt Soul. It matches Extract Aspects' ribbon feature. The actual value in Extract Aspects lies in reaction attacks against analyzed creatures.

Rule Bending is very situational. I would say that it's borderline useless in general, but if you often find yourself in situations where it will be useful then it will of course be useful.

"The actual value in Extract Aspects lies in reaction attacks against analyzed creatures."
Ohhh... I had actually missed that! That makes sense. And yeah, I can see that the HP knowledge doesn't make up for that (although I still like it for flavour). I'll see if we can boost that a bit.

Ok, spitballing a bit here. How would you feel about something like: "At the end of each of your turns, choose a non-player creature you can see. The DM tells you if that creature intends to make a weapon attack, a spell attack, cast any other damage-dealing spell, cast any other spell, or do something else with its action on its next turn. The DM abides by that declaration if possible". It feels nicely meta-knowledge, but may be too strong or too hard to adjudicate; or possibly be taking the schtick a bit far!

That seems very weird to me. It also breaks down if the target is not next in the initiative order. A lot could happen between the warlock's turn and the target's turn. Which in a lot of cases would either cause the target to do something that doesn't make sense or turn the feature in to a negative since the target fory something different. I guess it might work, but it would be received very different from table to table.
